# Google map api v3: SearchBox. Emulating press Enter button

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When you enter some text in SearchBox it will show you a drop-down with a few choices but if you instead press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button it will return most corresponding answer immediatelly.

How to achieve this behavior programatically?

I tried to emulate press <kbd>Enter</kbd> event on this control and calling `.getPlaces()` method manually but nothing happens.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Search for other question using "google like search box" or "google like dropdown box". You will get a lot of similar questions.

Comment: Lot of similar, but anyone doesn't answer this question. Can you propose some answer?

Comment: Sorry, no. Never did something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the listeners for the `searchBox` will be bound on `focus` and removed on `blur`.

So you must **first trigger the focus-event** and then the `keydown`-event of the input associated with the searchBox.

When you `trigger` the `keydown`-event, pass as argument an object with the property `keyCode:13`

```
//input associated with the searchBox
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

google.maps.event.trigger( input, 'focus')
google.maps.event.trigger( input, 'keydown', {keyCode:13})
```